# How do i make my routes.map display my components correctly

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-router-dom

It is something problem with my map below that is declared down in App.js because it worked before  and i have my route array with all the components that i want to click on and choose from but i can't make nave-bar show by click for example on Add Robot on my button?
I have tried long time with this and wonder if i declaring component = {} correctly?
I have 5 Navbar and want to click on them so each component are showing one at time correctly!
I have objects in my routes array should i try not to declare component = {} with something else?.How can i make it display this correctly without getting any error when clicking on my navbar tabs and not to make it errors.

How should i rewrite my routes.map so that my Nav-Bar is working?

```
{routes.map(({path, component:C}) => (
  <Route
    path={path}
    component={<C/>}
  />))
}
```

Below down is my App.js

```
    import React, { Component } from 'react';
    import {
        Link,
        Route,
        Switch
    } from 'react-router-dom';
    import { BrowserRouter as Router } from 'react-router-dom';
    import { connect } from 'react-redux';
    import {
        setSearchField,
        requestRobots,
        setName,
        setUserName,
        setEmail,
        addRobot,
        updateRobot,
        deleteRobot
    } from '../actions';
    import CardList from '../components/CardList';
    import SearchBox from '../components/SearchBox';
    import Scroll from '../components/Scroll';
    import ErrorBoundry from '../components/ErrorBoundry';
    import AddRobot from '../components/AddRobot';
    import UppdateRobot from '../components/UpdateRobot';
    import DeleteRobot from '../components/DeleteRobot';
    import NavBar from '../components/NavBar.js';
    import './App.css';

    // parameter state comes from index.js provider store state(rootReducers)
    const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
        return {
            searchField: state.searchRobots.searchField,
            robots: state.manage_data.robots,
            isPending: state.manage_data.isPending,
            name: state.manage_data.name,
            username: state.manage_data.username,
            email: state.manage_data.email,
        }
    }

    // dispatch the DOM changes to call an action. note mapStateToProps returns object, mapDispatchToProps returns function
    // the function returns an object then uses connect to change the data from redecers.
    const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
        return {
            onSearchChange: (event) => dispatch(setSearchField(event.target.value)),
            onRequestRobots: () => dispatch(requestRobots()),
            get_name: (event) => dispatch(setName(event.target.value)),
            get_username: (event) => dispatch(setUserName(event.target.value)),
            get_email: (event) => dispatch(setEmail(event.target.value)),
            add_robot: () => dispatch(addRobot()),
            uppdate_robot: () => dispatch(updateRobot())
        }
    }


    ///{path:'/delRobo',
    ///  component:'SearchBox',
    ///searchChange: (id) => onSearchChange(id) 
    ///},

    class App extends Component {
        componentDidMount() {
            console.log(this.props.userinfo);
            this.props.onRequestRobots();
        }

        render() {
                const {
                    robots,
                    searchField,
                    onSearchChange,
                    isPending,
                    get_name,
                    name,
                    get_username,
                    username,
                    get_email,
                    email,
                    add_robot,
                    uppdate_robot
                } = this.props;
                const stylecur = {
                    fill: 'currentcolor'
                };
                const filteredRobots = robots.filter(robot => {
                    return robot.name.toLowerCase().includes(searchField.toLowerCase());
                })
                const routes = [{
                        path: '/addRobo',
                        component: AddRobot,
                    },
                    {
                        path: '/updateRobo',
                        component: UppdateRobot,
                    },
                    {
                        path: '/searchRobo',
                        component: SearchBox,
                    }
                ];
                return ( <
                        Router >
                        <
                        div className = 'tc' >

                        <
                        header className = "bg-white black-80 tc pv4 avenir" >
                        <
                        a href = ""
                        className = "bg-black-80 ba b--black dib pa3 w2 h2 br-100" >
                        <
                        svg className = "white"
                        data - icon = "skull"
                        viewBox = "0 0 32 32"
                        style = {
                            stylecur
                        } >
                        <
                        title > skull icon < /title><path d="M16 0 C6 0 2 4 2 14 L2 22 L6 24 L6 30 L26 30 L26 24 L30 22 L30 14 C30 4 26 0 16 0 M9 12 A4.5 4.5 0 0 1 9 21 A4.5 4.5 0 0 1 9 12 M23 12 A4.5 4.5 0 0 1 23 21 A4.5 4.5 0 0 1 23 12"></path > < /svg> <
                        /a> <
                        h1 className = "mt2 mb0 baskerville i fw1 f1" > RoboFriends < /h1> <
                        h2 className = "mt2 mb0 f6 fw4 ttu tracked" > Create an ensembe of Robot with your friends! < /h2> <
                        nav className = "bt bb tc mw7 center mt4" >
                        <
                        a className = "f6 f5-l link bg-animate black-80 hover-bg-lightest-blue dib pa3 ph4-l"
                        href = "/" > Home < /a> <
                        a className = "f6 f5-l link bg-animate black-80 hover-bg-light-green dib pa3 ph4-l" > < Link to = {
                            '/addRobo'
                        }
                        className = "nav-link" > Add Robot < /Link></a >
                        <
                        a className = "f6 f5-l link bg-animate black-80 hover-bg-light-blue dib pa3 ph4-l" > < Link to = {
                            '/updateRobo'
                        }
                        className = "nav-link" > Update Robot < /Link></a >
                        <
                        a className = "f6 f5-l link bg-animate black-80 hover-bg-light-pink dib pa3 ph4-l" > < Link to = {
                            '/searchRobo'
                        }
                        className = "nav-link" > Search Robot < /Link></a >
                        <
                        a className = "f6 f5-l link bg-animate black-80 hover-bg-light-yellow dib pa3 ph4-l" > < Link to = {
                            '/delRobo'
                        }
                        className = "nav-link" > Delete Robot < /Link></a >
                        <
                        /nav> <
                        /header> <
                        Switch > {
                            routes.map(({
                                    path,
                                    component: C
                                }) => ( <
                                    Route path = {
                                        path
                                    }
                                    component = {
                                        < C / >
                                    }
                                    />))}                                  <
                                    /Switch>   <
                                    Scroll > {
                                        isPending ? < h1 > Loading < /h1> : <
                                        ErrorBoundry >
                                        <
                                        CardList robots = {
                                            filteredRobots
                                        }
                                        /> <
                                        /ErrorBoundry>
                                    } <
                                    /Scroll> <
                                    /div> <
                                    /Router>
                                );
                            }
                        }

                        // action done from mapDispatchToProps will channge state from mapStateToProps
                        export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(App)
```

Comment: Your code still has an invalid react prop/attribute in the SVG element. `data - icon = "skull"` isn't valid syntax, should be camalCased as `dataIcon="skull"`. Please post syntactically correct and formatted JSX so it is easier to read. Please also include what the errors are.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You render the component incorrectly, it should be just the component, not JSX

```
{routes.map(({ path, component: Component }) => (
  <Route
    path={path}
    component={Component} // sans the angle brackets </>
  />))
}
```